Trouble with compiling my keras_model_sequential()
I am working through Deep Learning with an R book and in the first couple of chapters there are already a lot of errors.
So I've figured out how to install keras and tensorflow, like this:
# install.packages("remotes") 
# remotes::install_github("rstudio/reticulate", force = TRUE) 
# remotes::install_github(sprintf("rstudio/%s", c("tensorflow", "keras"))) 
# reticulate::miniconda_uninstall() # start with a blank slate
# reticulate::install_miniconda() 
# #keras::install_keras() 
# #keras::install_keras(method = "conda", conda = "auto") 
# library(keras) 
# tensorflow::install_tensorflow(conda = "auto", envname = "r-reticulate", version = "release") 
# reticulate::use_condaenv(condaenv = "r-reticulate", conda = "auto", required = TRUE)

Then I can import the mnist dataset normally.
mnist <- keras::dataset_mnist()

After this I use the keras_model_sequential function like this:
model1 <-
  keras_model_sequential(list(
    layer_dense(
      units = 512,
      input_shape = c(28, 28),
      activation = "relu",
      name = "layer1"
    ),
    layer_dense(
      units = 10,
      activation = "softmax",
      name = "output"
    )
  ))

When I then try to compile it the following error code appears:
model1 %>% keras::compile(optimizer = "rmsprop",
                          loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                          metrics = "accuracy")

Error: Fehler in UseMethod("compile") : nicht anwendbare Methode für 'compile' auf Objekt der Klasse "c('keras.models.sequential.Sequential', 'keras.models.model.Model', 'keras.backend.tensorflow.trainer.TensorFlowTrainer', 'keras.trainers.trainer.Trainer', 'keras.layers.layer.Layer', 'keras.backend.tensorflow.layer.TFLayer', 'keras.backend.tensorflow.trackable.KerasAutoTrackable', 'tensorflow.python.trackable.autotrackable.AutoTrackable', 'tensorflow.python.trackable.base.Trackable', 'keras.ops.operation.Operation', 'python.builtin.object')" angewendet`

So I figured that the class which is produced by my keras_model_sequential must be different from keras.engine.training.Model, which would be expected as per documentation.
When I call summary(model1) the following appears:
When I call class(model1) there are multiple results:
[1] "keras.models.sequential.Sequential" 

[2] "keras.models.model.Model" 

[3] "keras.backend.tensorflow.trainer.TensorFlowTrainer" 

[4] "keras.trainers.trainer.Trainer" 

[5] "keras.layers.layer.Layer" 

[6] "keras.backend.tensorflow.layer.TFLayer" 

[7] "keras.backend.tensorflow.trackable.KerasAutoTrackable" 

[8] "tensorflow.python.trackable.autotrackable.AutoTrackable" 

[9] "tensorflow.python.trackable.base.Trackable" 

[10] "keras.ops.operation.Operation" 

[11] "python.builtin.object"

How do I get keras_model_sequential to produce the correct class? I figured out that's my problem. Or what else could be my problem?

I had exactly the same problem and just got it solved by remove.packages("keras") then devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras"). compile() in 'keras3' package works well.
I found the solution here https://github.com/rstudio/keras3/issues/853
